# Change to non-modal in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, non-modal

How can I change it to non-modal ?
If button is clicked then cursor doesn't change. If I change it to non-modal then it should be ok.

```
def start_new_proc():
    # text.config(cursor="clock")
    root.config(cursor="clock")
    text.config(state="normal")
    command = "ping 8.8.8.8 -c 1"
    proc = Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
        line = line.decode('utf-8')
        if line == '':
            break
        text.insert("end", line)
    proc.wait()
    # text.config(cursor="")
    root.config(cursor="")
    text.config(state="disable")



root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, state="disabled")
text.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Run", command=start_new_proc)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by non-modal and what is the problem. Your code seems to work as expected for me.

Comment: the cursor doesn't change. modal means that I can't do anything during processing. @Henry

Comment: Within `tkinter` context, your example is already non-modal since there is no `.grab_set` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using threading.

```
import threading
def ping_func(output):
    command = "ping 8.8.8.8 -c 1"
    proc = Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
        line = line.decode('utf-8')
        if line == '':
            break
        output.append(line)
    

def check_complete():
    if not ping_thread.is_alive():
        root.config(cursor = "")
        button.config(state = "normal")
    else:
        root.after(100, check_complete)

def check_output():
    if output != []:
        text.config(state = "normal")
        text.insert("end", output.pop(0))
        text.config(state = "disabled")
    root.after(100, check_output)

def start_new_proc():
    #text.config(cursor="clock")
    root.config(cursor="clock")
    button.config(state = "disabled") #Disable button until process completed
    global output, ping_thread
    output = []
    ping_thread = threading.Thread(target = ping_func, args = (output,))
    ping_thread.start()
    check_output()
    check_complete()



root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, state="disabled")
text.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Run", command=start_new_proc)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

By putting the command execution in a thread, it doesn't hold up the tkinter thread. The function `ping_func` is what the thread runs. It does what the program did before, but the output is different. Because tkinter isn't thread safe, you can't use tkinter objects in other threads. Therefore we need to pass a variable instead which can then be polled by the tkinter thread. This is what the `output` list is for. The output from `ping_func` is appended to `output`. To check the contents of `output` and insert it into the Text widget, we need a function `check_output`. This calls itself every 100ms to check if the contents of output have changed. If they have it inserts the new line into the Text widget. There is also  `check_complete` which checks every 100ms if the thread has ended and changes the cursor and enables the button if it has.

Comment: Do you know what's modal and non-modal ? Where can I find a code example. Can't find in google. @Henry

Comment: You told me what modal means?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach, it uses threading and queue to not block the `.mainloop()` and to not call `tkinter` methods from another thread (which may potentially break it):

```py
import tkinter as tk
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue


def start_new_proc():
    # text.config(cursor="clock")
    root.config(cursor="clock")
    text.config(state="normal")
    queue = Queue()
    Thread(target=lambda: run_proc(queue)).start()
    update_text(queue)


def after_proc():
    # text.config(cursor="")
    root.config(cursor="")
    text.config(state="disable")


def update_text(queue):
    data = queue.get()
    if data == 'break':
        after_proc()
        return
    text.insert('end', data)
    root.after(100, update_text, queue)


def run_proc(queue):
    command = "ping 8.8.8.8"
    proc = Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
        line = line.decode('utf-8')
        if line == '':
            queue.put('break')
            break
        queue.put(line)
    # proc.wait()


root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, state="disabled")
text.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Run", command=start_new_proc)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Quick explanation:

When you click the button, it calls `start_new_proc()`:

Now first all the configurations are run so now the cursor and text are configured (note that the clock cursor is visible only when the cursor is not on Text widget, since the config for text widget is commented out)

Then a queue object is created, this will allow to safely communicate between threads (and it will get garbage collected once the function "stops")

Then a thread is started where the `cmd` command is run (oh and I changed it a bit (removed "-c 1") because I couldn't test otherwise). So every iteration the data is put into the queue for the main thread to safely receive it, other stuff is the same, also notice that there is '"break"' put into queue once the loop has to stop, so that the other end knows to stop too (probably better to place some object since `"break"` can be placed there by `line` variable)

Then the `update_text()` function is called which receives data from the queue and then inserts it to the text widget (there is also the `"break"` check) and then the `.after()` method for making the function loop without blocking the `.mainloop()` (and also when `"break"` apppears then configuration function gets called to config the state and cursor)

Comment: Do you know what's modal and non-modal ? Where can I find a code example. Can't find in google. @Matiiss

Comment: @Alex per your own words: _modal means that I can't do anything during processing_ so therefore non-modal would mean that you can do something during processing, the only processing I could think of here was the Popen part so I made it so that while it executes, you can still interact with tkinter (semi-well because apparently `.get()` method for Queue takes quite a while)

Comment: and also the thing that first came to mind when hearing `modal` was what I have had experience with in the past couple of days when working with html, I came across this thing modal which is basically like a dialog box for web browsers or sth